# please help me with this while loop

Tags: java

please rectify my mistake.

```java
    package com.company;
    
    public class practice2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            int a = 5;
    
            while (a > 0) {
                while (a>0) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                    a--;
                }
                a--;
            }
        }
    }
```

above code will work one but below.........why do i need to assign it to a new variable to use it in a new loop.

```java
    package com.company;
    
    public class practice2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            int a = 5;
    
            while (a > 0) {
                a=b;
                while (b>0) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                    b--;
                }
                a--;
            }
        }
    }
```

to print:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

This is not a homework question i am just not able to grab the concept.

Comment: You'll need to print a newline somewhere in those loops. Also, why use `while` when there's a pretty serviceable `for`?

Comment: i was practicing while loops and trying to have some confidence in all types of loops

Comment: where should i put newline.......

Comment: After the innermost loop has ended. But that won't be sufficient. I suggest you use a different variable in the innermost loop and initialize it to `a`. Then, since I basically gave you the solution, you should try and do it backwards (one `*` in the first line, two in the second etc) to check whether you understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 class HelloWorld {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          int i=0,j=0,a=5;
          while (a > i) {
          j=i;
          while (a>j) {
            System.out.print("*");
            j++;
          }
          System.out.println();
          i++;
          }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Please read  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) (emphasis on *answer*).

Answer (score 1):

You could use only one loop to do so, and using the `.repeat()` method for repeating the stars

**Edited:** calling a method to do that work is better :)

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        printStarsTriangle(5);
    }
    static void printStarsTriangle(int n) {
        for(int i = n;i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.print("*".repeat(i) + (i != 1 ? "\n" : ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code will now print this:

```
*
*
*
*
*
```

Because you haven't specified how much times you need to print the stars in each line.

To fix this, just change the `System.out.print("*");` to `System.out.print("*" * a);`

This means that you need to print the character `*` "a" times in each loop. Since the value of a in decreasing, your problem is solved.

You can also try to use for loop instead of while loop. This [website](https://www.codevscolor.com/java-print-triangle-reverse-triangle) will help you with it

Comment: it is showing an error

Comment: `System.out.print("*" * a);` this is definitely wrong. You may be thinking of python, where multiplying a string does what you meant, but that's not a thing in java.

Comment: I.....didn't think of it. I tried your code in dart, so this worked. I think this website will help you with this:  https://www.codevscolor.com/java-print-triangle-reverse-triangle